# Redirecting to payment gateway in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, paypal, payment-gateway

I am doing payment via MVC3 application. My question is how to redirect to external payment gateway(for netbanking) with some hidden input from MVC application.

I have view page which has credit card and netbanking option which is selected based radio button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "hdReferenceNumber" }, { "name", "hdReferenceNumber" } })    

    </article>
    <!-- Start Code  -     payment page - Payment Option Selection section  -->
    <article>
        <section>
            <div>               
                <p>Please select your payment option.</p>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButton("PaymentOption", "1", "Credit Card", false, Model.PaymentOption, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "RdCreditCard" }, { "name", "PaymentoptionSelection" }, { "value", "Credit Card" }, { "list", "{'1:Credit Card'}" } })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                                @Html.RadioButton("PaymentOption", "2", "Netbanking", false, Model.PaymentOption, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "RdNetbanking" }, { "name", "PaymentoptionSelection" }, { "value", "Netbanking" }, { "list", "{'2:Netbanking'}" } }) 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
    <!-- End Code  -     payment page - Payment Option Selection section  -->

    <!-- Start Code  -     payment page - Credit Card Details Entry Section -->
    <article id="creditCard">
        <section>
            <div>
                <h1>Credit Card</h1>               
                <p>Please enter credit card information.</p>                
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Card Number</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CardNumberCol1, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "txtCardNumberCol1" }, { "name", "CardNumberCol1" }, { "maxLength", "4" }, { "onkeyup", "movetoNext(this, 'txtCardNumberCol2')" } })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CardNumberCol2, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "txtCardNumberCol2" }, { "name", "CardNumberCol2" }, { "maxLength", "4" }, { "onkeyup", "movetoNext(this, 'txtCardNumberCol3')" } })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CardNumberCol3, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "txtCardNumberCol3" }, { "name", "CardNumberCol3" }, { "maxLength", "4" }, { "onkeyup", "movetoNext(this, 'txtCardNumberCol4')" } })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CardNumberCol4, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "txtCardNumberCol4" }, { "name", "CardNumberCol4" }, { "maxLength", "4" }, { "onkeyup", "movetoNext(this, 'monthPicker')" } })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td colspan="4">Please enter card number by 4 digits, left-aligned</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Month/Year</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ValidMonth, new List<SelectListItem> { }, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "monthPicker" },  })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ValidYear, new List<SelectListItem> { }, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "yearPicker" }, { } })
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>                    
                </table>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit"  id="Settle" name="Settle"  value="PaymentScreen_Settle"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="LnkCCardCancel">Cancel</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
    <!-- End Code  -     payment page - Credit Card Details Entry Section -->

    <!-- Start Code  -    payment page - Netbanking Section -->     
    <article id="netbanking">
        <section">
            <div">
                <h1>Netbanking</h1>               
                <p>You will be directed to your bank site.</p>
                @Html.Hidden("ver","abcd")
                @Html.Hidden("bill", "abcd")
                @Html.Hidden("shop", "abcd")
                @Html.Hidden("success", "http://www.abcd.com/abcd/success")
                @Html.Hidden("failure", "http://www.abcd.com/abcd/failure")
                @Html.Action("https://www.netbankingsite.com/abcdefgh12345")
                <ul>
                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Next", "PolicyDetailsScreen", "PolicyDetailsUC", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "btnNext" }, { "name", "btnNext" }, { "value", "btnNext" },})*@
                    <li>                   
                    <input type="submit" id="BtnNext" name="BtnNext" value="Next" data-action="@Url.Action("https://https://www.netbankingsite.com/abcdefgh12345")" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="LnkCStoreCancel">Cancel</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
    <!-- End Code -     payment page - Netbanking  Section -->

    <!-- Start Code  -     payment page - Back Button section  -->
    <section>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back", "AgreementScreen", "PaymentUC", new { policyNumber = Model.newPolicyDetails.ReferenceNumber }, new { id = "btnBack", name = "btnBack"})
    </section>
    <!-- End Code  -     payment page - Back Button section  -->  
}
```

I have completed credit card payment completely. Now i need to do netbanking code. The problem is i have a Payment URL

```
https://https://www.netbankingsite.com/abcdefgh12345
```

with few hidden input for the abov URL which must be redirected to by using POST method.

**1st Problem**
I am struggling how to redirect to the site from MVC3.

**2nd problem:**
Since i have credit card and netbanking in same view page, if i click respective payment button, the credit card controller is called. Is there a way to use 2 @html.begin form in view page, so that i can post separately for credit card and netbanking.

**3rd Problem**
I must have both credit card and netbanking in same view page. if i select netbanking radio button, then netbanking part view page section will be displayed below the radio button for user, and credit card page will be hidden to user.This hiding part is done by using jquery. And i am fetching details from DB and assiging it to view page html controls via model.

So how can i do netbanking redirection from view page without affecting credit card and only passing hidden input to the URL via POST action. if i do credit card payment then i should not post any input to netbanking url and should not redirect. I am quite a bit confused how handle it. So reaching out to fellow techies...! I know this must be done as web service, but doing in mvc is requirement.

Thanks for the help and patience to read this big question.

Comment: The whole functionality which u want can only be implemented with jquery...

Comment: there must be same way... but i am sure we can do it in mvc